# How to create a record with the current user

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am trying to add a create controller method for a child table of application user.  I can't figure out how to populate the user id.  I'm in the process of learning mvc and this seems like such a basic concept, but I can't get it to work.  Here is my class.

```
public class Ticket
{
    [Key]
    public long Id { get; set; }

    [StringLength(128), MinLength(3)]
    [ForeignKey("AspNetUser")]
    public virtual string AspNetUserId { get; set; }

    public virtual ApplicationUser AspNetUser { get; set; }

    public DateTime Date { get; set; }

    public string Request { get; set; }
}
```

Here is my index - hopefully pulling only records associated to the current user.  I don't have seed data setup, so I have to get create working in order to test this, but the view comes up.

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        //var userId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
        var userId = UserManager.FindById(User.Identity.GetUserId());

        var tickets = db.Tickets.Where(m => m.AspNetUser == userId); ;
        return View(tickets.ToList());
    }
```

My create get which also comes up, but doesn't seem to be linked up.

```
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

And here is my troublesome create post method.  When I click submit nothing happens.

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "Id,AspNetUserId,Date,Request")] Ticket ticket)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        ticket.AspNetUserId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
        db.Tickets.Add(ticket);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    return View(ticket);
}
```

Within my view I have a @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id) for the Id, but since it's not posting I assume my ModelState is not valid.

So frustrating.

Comment: Hey @MVC_Future_Guru If you show your HTML form it might be easier to help. If you make a breakpoint at that if statement and hover over .IsValid what does it say? If it's false you can always dig down and see what's up. If it's true set another break point on the db.Tickets.Add line and hover over ticket and take a look at what got bound.

Comment: You have a couple of issues:  1. Your `Index` action will list ALL tickets in the system.  The `.Include(...)` is only ensuring that the `AspNetUser` property is being populated.  You need to include a `Where(...)` clause to filter to the currently logged in user.  2. Without the form (HTML) we can't see how you're setting the `AspNetUserId`.  As mentioned, you need to perform some pretty basic debugging to see what's happening.  Inspect the `ModelState` - if it's invalid, it'll also contain details of **why** it's invalid.

Comment: .IsValid is false, and I don't have anything within the form for AspNetUserId.  The scaffolding put a dropdown list, but I took and it out and hoped that my line within the controller would suffice.  Do I have to add something in the view to declare the AspNetUserId as the current user?

Comment: That looks better.  Now, if `.IsValid` is false, inspect the error messages that are contained within, and report them back via an update to the question.  It is highly likely that this will contain all the detail you need to fix the issue.